# How to navigate in a prism master-detail Xamarin.Forms application

Tags: navigation, xamarin.forms, prism, master-detail

I' creating my first Prism/XF application. The main page is a MasterDetailPage. I've read that to change the detail page from the master page VM, I just have to call NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NewDetailPage") from the MasterPageViewModel.

When I do this, the master page changes, and becomes NewDetailPage. I want to keep the MasterDatilPage and change it's detail page.

Here is my App class

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
{
    public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer = null) : base(initializer) { }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MenuPrincipalPage/ClubHousePage");
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes()
    {
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MenuPrincipalPage>();
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<ClubHousePage>();
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<AProposPage>();
    }
}
```

This works great. The application is launched with the correct master (MenuPrincipalPage) and the correct detail (ClubHousePage).

I MenuPrincipalPageViewModel (the master page VM), I tried a few things. First navigate directly to the detail page :

```
    public DelegateCommand AProposCommand { get;  private set; }

    private void APropos()
    {
        NavigationService.NavigateAsync("AProposPage", );
    }
```

The MasterPage is changed.

I then tried this :

```
    public DelegateCommand AProposCommand { get;  private set; }

    private void APropos()
    {
        NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MenuPrincipalPage/AProposPage");
    }
```

The MasterPage is also changed.

This code works :

```
    public DelegateCommand AProposCommand { get;  private set; }

    private void APropos()
    {
        NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/MenuPrincipalPage/AProposPage");
    }
```

But isn't there a problem here ? The full navigation stack is erased I think.

Did I do something wrong ?

Many thanks in advance for your advices,
Julien

Answer (score 2):

It's working exactly like it should.  What makes you think you are changing the MasterDetailPage?  Is it because you don't have a hamburger menu?  I am guess so, because how you have it setup now will result in a MasterDetailPage that has no hamburger menu and give the appearance of there not being a MasterDetailPage.  You can easily test this by navigating, and the swiping from the left edge to show the Master menu.

When using a MasterDetailPage you should be wrapping your detail in a NavigationPage.

`NavigationService.Navigate("MasterDetailPage/NavigationPage/Detail");`

Then any navigation done within the Detail page will automatically have a back button for it's navigation stack.

Comment: Hi Brian,

I added a NavigationPage but my problem is still there. In fact, my question is : Why should I have to put a / at the beginning of the navigation URL ?

The following code works :

    NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/MenuPrincipalPage/ContenuPage/AProposPage");

While this one doesn't :


    NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MenuPrincipalPage/ContenuPage/AProposPage");



The only difference is the / at the beginning.

Comment: When you place a "/" at the beginning you are resetting the navigation stack.  It sounds like you are doing something wrong.  If you are navigating from the Master simple use "NavigationPage/Target" and o not include the master detail page in the path. Check out this sample: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Forms/tree/master/HamburgerMenu

Comment: Hi Brian, using NavigationPage/Target will not show the back button in ViewA\ViewB\ViewC.
Only the hamburger menu on top